# Divide objects Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

I have this graphics in Illustrator.[image: ai image]

I would like to remove the portions of the globe outside the outlined path and I want the remaining earth and the space inside the path as two separate regions. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy the rounded rectangle shape. (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
- Select the globe
- Paste in Front (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)
- Select the newly pasted rounded rectangle and the globe
- Choose `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` from the menu.

For more information on Clipping Masks, check out the [Adobe Illustrator Help Files.](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/clipping-masks.html)

Comment: Thanks Scott. I had it done before I read your answer but I learned an easier way to do it when I followed your steps. Hope I will save time next time I do something similar. Thanks a million.